# Access another attribute in Angular attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called `selectable` that will add a `selected` attribute to the element, when the keyboard arrows select the item (which is in a grid). I then have another directive called `remote-action`.

Is it possible to something like `remote-action="hasAttribute('selected') ? 'Open' : false"` where `hasAttribute` is what I'm looking for, or a way to get a value of another attribute inside the value of different attribute.

Not every `selectable` will have a `remote-action` and vice versa, so I don't think I can do this in the code of either directive, also some elements will have isolated scope and some won't.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to approach this is with the `require` config option and a controller on the `selectable` directive that exposes the `selected` property. An outline of the code:

```
app.directive('selectable', function() {
    return {
        ...
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var self = this;

            this.selected = false; // (1)

            $element.on('...', function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    self.selected = ... // (2)
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

app.directive('remoteAction', function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: '?selectable', // (3)
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, selectableCtrl) {
            if( selectableCtrl !== null ) { // (4)
                scope.$watch( // (5)
                    function() {
                        return selectableCtrl.selected;
                    },
                    function(newval, oldval) {
                        ...
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Explanation:

1. The `selectable` directive has a controller that exposes the `selected` property
2. The `selected` property gets updated according to some logic - in the example above when a DOM event occurs
3. The `remoteAction` directive optionally requires the `selectable` directive in the same element
4. Angular passes `null` as the controller, if the collaborating directive is not found
5. The `remoteAction` directive watches the value of the `selected` property and takes action accordingly

Comment: This would make the view/html not the official record though, and would be tying together 2 unrelated directives. What if another usage of remote-action wants to use a different attribute?

Comment: The directives on a single element share their `$attrs`. You could use this, i.e. one watches the attrs, the other sets values to it. I still think it is much cleaner with cooperating directives, perhaps it is not the `selectable` that should be shared but another, generic one - or it may be that I have not understood your needs correctly.

Comment: This is my idea of cooperating directives: http://jsfiddle.net/om0c875j/1/ - The `selectable` and the `remoteAction` depend on the `attributeHolder` to cooperate, but the view is "the official record".

Comment: That is slightly better, but it still requires a selected property that duplicates the selected attribute. And implies that remote-action needs attributes, when it's value can be based on anything. Is there no way to access the current element in a attribute value?

Comment: Not by default AFAIK.